# Equality almost everywhere on products

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $f$ and $g$ be two measurable functions that are almost everywhere equal on 
a product of two measured spaces $X_1\times X_2$.
 (Edit )We suppose the measures to be sigma-finite.
And the product measure is on the product sigma-algebra (so non completed).

Is the following true :

"$f(x_1,\cdot)=g(x_1,\cdot)$" almost everywhere (in $X_2$), for almost all $x_1\in X_1$.

Comment: I dont understand, your two sets are just exactly the same

Comment: In the first set, $x_1$ is fixed. In the second, we are allowing it to vary. That is  the difference. Because it can vary in the second, it follows that the first set is a subset of the second, but the second has Lebesgue measure zero, so must the first, as long as completion holds. If it doesn't then I don't know the answer, unfortunately, although I expect a false answer.

Comment: Thank you, i have another question, how do we show that the image by a projection of a lebesgue measurable set is also a lebesgue measurable set?

Comment: I am sorry to tell you (and myself!) this, but as it turns out, that is incorrect. It is not true that the projection of a Lebesgue measurable set is Lebesgue measurable in general. Try to construct an example yourself, using a non-measurable set. My proof is then INCORRECT, and the comment is deleted. I will look to correct it, and get back to you as soon as I can. Honest apologies on that.